# Where is the manual for pasting code on here?

Tags: support, editing, markdown

I want to post some terminal commands here.  But it comes out as one paragraph when I paste in this text box.  How do I format so that the information I am pasting stays the way it is and does not get mashed into one mass?

Comment: Your post will be closed as this is not the right place to ask this question. Nevertheless, give it a try yourself: click on the [**Ask Question**](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button yourself and hover your mouse over the editor options to read their meanings: you will find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the block of code and click the `{}` button in the toolbar above the editor box, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. If you prefer, you can do the same thing manually by indenting each line with four spaces; there must be an empty line above the code block.

You can also enclose your text in back ticks (`) if you only need a small amount of text to show in code form.  `like this`

You can find this by clicking the `(?)` button at the right of the editor toolbar, then click “Preformatted”.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the block of code does not work very well when located just after a list (whether ordered or unordered). In such cases it is often necessary to use more or less dirty workarounds or manually doubling the four space indentation for each lines...

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf The “right” way in this case is to insert a comment: `<!-- -->` after the list. If you intend the block by 8 spaces, it becomes part of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the right workaround, I'll remember it! :)

Comment: Thanks loads for the answer re highlighting and clicking the curly brackets.